# Simplify a recursive function in Maple

Tags: maple

I have the following problem. Out of the runtime analysis of an divide and conquer algorithm I got the following formula for the necessary flops:

```
flops(n): = (89+1/3)*n^3 + 2 * flops(n/2)
```

and

```
flops(1):= 0
```

I want to sum it up and to remove the recursion with Maple. But I do not get it working. Everytime Maple complains: *Error, (in flops) too many levels of recursion*

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have too much recursion because your code assumes `n`to be even for the stopping criterion to work. If you call your flops count function with `n`equal to 3, it will call the function with argument `3/2`and your recursion will never end. You could replace your function with

`flops(n) := (89+1/3)*n^3 + 2 * flops(floor(n/2))`

and use the criterion `flops(0) := 0`

But this will only work if you use numbers, not some arbitrary `N`. If you want to solve the recurrence equation, you should use the `rsolve`command:

`rsolve({flops(n) = (89+1/3)*n^3 + 2 * flops(n/2),flops(1)=0},flops(n));`

which will give you $\frac{1072}{9}n(n^2-1)$ as an answer to your problem.